# Connection Per User in webLoad(Radview)

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Whether Webload(Radview) contains anything similar to VSTS's WebTest Connection Model's Connection Per User

Answer (score 0):

Yes, in WebLOAD, it is called 'Multi threaded Virtual Clients'.

You set it up in the WebLOAD Console, Current Session Options -> Browser Parameters